# Getting error while using google data transfer to transfer multiple Json file from GCSto Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, stream, data-transfer, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting error while I'm trying to transfer file from Google cloud storage to google big query.
This is the error :

> failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT : Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more
> details.

When I look the error I have this :

> Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0:
> No such field: _ttl.

I don't understand where is the problem.
if I just try to transfer 1 files, the data is sent to my Bigquery table. but I need to transfer all the files every days.
This is my data format example :

```
{"createdAt":"2021-12-07T12:07:44.547Z","_lastChangedAt":1638878864561,"isMain":true,"__typename":"Accounting","name":"main","belongTo":"siewecarine","id":"d00ae4ad-c661-40b8-9e90-e0f53b2211fb","_version":1,"updatedAt":"2021-12-07T12:07:44.547Z"}
{"createdAt":"2021-12-07T12:09:12.583Z","_lastChangedAt":1638878952618,"isMain":false,"__typename":"Accounting","name":"test1","belongTo":"mbappe","id":"ee42db80-a6f4-400c-a089-061cc7eec967","_version":1,"updatedAt":"2021-12-07T12:09:12.583Z"}
```

My data come from a S3 bucket and I batch it from dynamodb.

Comment: Do some files contain _ttl field?

Comment: No my files do not content _ttl field

Comment: Does the table exist? If so, is the _ttl field exit in it?

Comment: no I created the table when I look the table schema I don't see it inside

Comment: I have resolved the issue

Comment: Any clues for the others that could have the same issue than you?

Comment: Hi, please remember to post your solution to help the community.

Comment: I changed the data format in s3 when streaming my data from Dynamodb to apache parquet(.parquet) by using a glue crawler and there were others fields that did not appear with Json format. I added those fieds to my table schema in bigquery and everything goes well